# First Brew got a high OG and planning to put apricots in the fermenter, will the yeast be able to get the sugar before the alcohol kills it off?

Tags: all-grain, specific-gravity

I went all grain BIAB straight off, recipe was kind of my own:

10l batch

- 1kg marris otter malt barley
- 1Kg wheat
- 100g oats
- 40g hallertauer hops in total
- 400g enhancer
- packet of witbier yeast (mangrove jacks) 8%
  alc tolerance

got a OG of 1.062 which I thought was high for this kind of beer and I was planning to add apricot puree from cans in a few days but starting to think this is a bad idea and is going to make the beer even sweeter. if people think this is not the case how long shall I wait before putting them in?

I also didn't do a starter for my yeast and I boiled away too much wort so I just boiled a standard electric kettle and topped it up at the end of the boil (don't know if this is a problem).
thanks

Im also thinking about bottles exploding if there's too much sugar left?
What kind of final gravity will be okay for bottling?

Comment: Did you calculate the estimated FG for the brew? Is your state OG before or after the top off? For witbier around 1.01 is pretty standard. That would get you to almost 7% abv. There are online calculator to estimate how much sugar fruit will add. Since with the wort alone you are getting close to the yeasts limit, I might check it out to see what you can expect.

Answer (score 1):

Adding apricot puree will be fine, I would add it a bit before you reach terminal gravity, personally. The apricot should not add much sweetness, as the majority of the sugars will be fermented out. Adding the water was fine, it will have lowered your OG a bit. In terms of bottling, the exact gravity doesn't matter much, as long as it's not changing unexpectedly. When you think the beer is done, measure the gravity every day. If it doesn't change over 3 days, you can be confident that it's done. At that point, it's safe to add priming sugar and bottle.